# Wrong underscan settings after reboot in 12.10 x64, with (fglrx open source) AMD HD7850

Tags: ati, fglrx

I used AMD CCC (administrative) to disable underscanning, but after reboot it underscans again, so I have to move the slider again after every reboot.

I tryed CCC non-administrative, but still have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is opening AMD CCC non-administrative and adjusting the over scan to 0, then reboot and it works. For some reason the admin side doesn't persist but non-admin does.